# setting up wordpress on ubuntu, directory permissions

Tags: apache2, wordpress

I have git cloned my wordpress repo into `/home/me/alliance`
I have edited `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

To contain

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    DocumentRoot /home/me/alliance
```

I have added myself to `www-data`

I have chowned the directory.

`chown -R me:www-data alliance`

I have checked the permissions.
`ls -al alliance`

`drwxrwxr-x 8 me www-data 4096 Apr  1 13:26 alliance`

I still get `Forbidden`

```
Forbidden    
You don't have permission to access / on this server.    
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at ...northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com Port 80
```

I do know that apache is working correctly, as I did manage to open the home page before I started trying to setup the site.

Answer (score 3):

```
<Directory /home/me/alliance>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

needs to be added to apache2.conf

Comment: Specifically 'Require all granted' is the new configuration for apache 2.4 where as 2.2 used order/allow directives.

Answer (score 0):

The owner of the folder should be www-data - not you.

`chown -R www-data:www-data alliance`

Comment: that doesn't seem to help, same problem.